# In mobile website, the mobile browsers asks me sporadically to open the next webpage on WHICH BROWSER? How can i remove this?

Tags: mobile, mobile-website, deep-linking

In my product's mobile website, when user is clicking something he/she is getting choice to choose the web browser.

Suppose user has opened website on android phone- on chrome browser. Now when he/she is clicking Next button, its telling him to choose the browser in which next link should be opened - For example: IE/Chrome/Opera. I want to remove this completely. Giving user choice of browser on every/multiple clicks is not required here. How do i remove this?

Suggestions please. (Someone suggested me it might have something to do with deep linking, but i am not sure about that). Any help/direction would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On android you should be able to open the link and hit always on the browser you want to use , don't use open once. Hope that helps!!

Comment: I want to change the code so that user doesn't see this browser choice pop-up. You are telling from user's perspective.

Comment: The problem is if user doesn't click 'always' and opts for 'only for this time' option, the choice of browser keeps on coming every time.